# Google Maps Api 3: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setCenter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, maps

I have been trying to get my geocoder working this morning for the following URL but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong: http://www.dlplaw.com/media/map.html

When clicking encode, the geocoder is doing it's job and returning the correct Lat / Long coordinates but it gets hung up on setCenter.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setCenter' of undefined
```

I tried to follow the Google example here and can't understand why this won't work:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`map` is not in scope.  You declare `map` twice – once in the global scope and once in `initialize`, but you only set the `map` in `initialize` (the global `map` is shadowed).

Remove the `var` from `var map = new google.maps.Map(...);`  (but not the `var map;` at the top).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see that. Thank you for your help Josh. Do you know if there is also a way to ensure one map layer always loads before the other? I haven't been able to find it searching all morning.

Comment: I'm not sure... you might try opening another question.

Comment: Thank you. Had the same error. I know ask me why I didn't see that. *hmmm*... whatever, works now :) +1