# How can I do Realtime Google Maps Geolocation Tracking with Angular js

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs

I need's to develop Real-time Geo location tracking in showed in google maps. I followed this tutorial : https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2017-02-02-realtime-google-maps-tracking-and-live-geolocation-with-javascript/  I tried to implement in Angular js because for mobile app.

The Code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/pubnub-angular/pubnub-angular-4.0.2.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
 </div>
<script>
var helloWorldApp = angular.module('myApp', ["pubnub.angular.service"]);
helloWorldApp.run(['Pubnub', function (Pubnub) {
    Pubnub.init({
       publishKey: 'pub-c-d529ea1a-f5b0-4b1e-a476-8e631139624b',
       subscribeKey: 'sub-c-7cc68612-e6aa-11e6-a5f4-02ee2ddab7fe'
    });
}]);
helloWorldApp.controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', 'Pubnub', function($scope, Pubnub) {

    console.log("Entered into HelloCtrl");
    $scope.firstName = "John";
 $scope.lastName = "Doe";
 
  $scope.lat = 37.8199;
    $scope.lng = -122.4783;

    var map;
    var mark;
    var lineCoords = [];
 var initialize = function() {
      map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {center:{lat:lat,lng:lng},zoom:12});
      mark = new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:lat, lng:lng}, map:map});
      lineCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.lng));
    };
    $scope.initialize = initialize;

    var redraw = function(payload) {
      lat = payload.message.lat;
      lng = payload.message.lng;

     // map.setCenter({lat:lat, lng:lng, alt:0});
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
      mark.setPosition({lat:lat, lng:lng, alt:0});
      lineCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

      var lineCoordinatesPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: lineCoords,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#2E10FF'
      });
      
      lineCoordinatesPath.setMap(map);
    };

    var pnChannel = "map-channel";

    var pubnub = new PubNub({
       publishKey: 'pub-c-d529ea1a-f5b0-4b1e-a476-8e631139624b',
       subscribeKey: 'sub-c-7cc68612-e6aa-11e6-a5f4-02ee2ddab7fe'
    });

    pubnub.subscribe({channels: [pnChannel]});
    pubnub.addListener({message:redraw});

    setInterval(function() {
      pubnub.publish({channel:pnChannel, message:{lat:window.lat + 0.001, lng:window.lng + 0.01}});
    }, 5000);
  
    $scope.subscribe = function () {
        Pubnub.subscribe({
            channel: 'hello_world',
            triggerEvents: ['message']
        })
    }
}]);
  
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD1kFmJoDZUAYtlluamZbet8T5WAgLXZ5c&callback=initialize"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error is :

```html
angularpra.html:41 Entered into HelloCtrl
angularpra.html:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined
    at Object.redraw [as message] (file:///C:/Users/suresh/Desktop/angularpra.html:66:7)
    at https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:1974:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _class.announceMessage (https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:1973:24)
    at https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:1883:36
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _class._processSubscribeResponse (https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:1817:17)
    at onResponse (https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:2321:8)
    at https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:4500:13
    at Request.callback (https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js:5209:4)
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636773/google-maps-api-3-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-setcenter-of-undefin - maybe same/similar issue.